# Build KNN graph over some subset of Node features

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, dgl

I have a point cloud that I want to use a graph neural network on. Each point in the point cloud is characterised by its positional coordinates as well as it's color. So a single node is `(X, Y, Z, C)`.

Now I want to apply an Edge Convolution on this (as described [in the DGL Edge-Conv example](https://github.com/dmlc/dgl/tree/master/examples/pytorch/pointcloud/edgeconv), and to do it I should build a Nearest Neighbors graph on `(X, Y, Z)` (**And not on C**), then use all the 4 properties as features for my neural network.

What would be a clean and efficient way to do this? (I have a lot of data so I want to batch and collate well)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have a tensor `pc` of shape `(NUM_POINTS, 4)` where each row is `(X, Y, Z, C)`, then you could use `sklearn` as follows:

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import dgl

k = 3 # number of neighbours you want

neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=k)
neigh.fit(pc[:, :3].numpy()) # selects only (X, Y, Z)

knn = neigh.kneighbors_graph()
graph = dgl.from_scipy(knn)
graph.ndata['x'] = pc
```

I would recommend saving these graphs to disk, so they are not computed each time you train etc.